# Swagger Editor creates wrong path for Rest endpoint

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-editor

So, I need to recreate my rest endpoints using Swagger. For that I am using the Swagger editor at editor.swagger.io

To call my actual rest endpoint, I need this path: `http://localhost:8080/phonenumbersmanagement/api/v1/areacodes/1`

Sadly, Swagger Editor creates a similar path, which I cannot use: `http://localhost:8080/phonenumbersmanagement/api/v1/areacodes?id=1`

It is a GET-request. I am getting a `405 - Method not allowed`

My code in the Swagger editor looks like this:

```
/areacodes:
    post:
      tags:
      - "areacode"
      summary: "Add AreaCode"
      description: ""
      operationId: "addAreaCode"
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "add areacode"
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/AreaCode"
      responses:
        "405":
          description: "Invalid input"
    get:
      tags:
      - "areacode"
      summary: "Get Areacode"
      description: ""
      operationId: "getAreaCodeById"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "id"
        in: "query"
        description: "Status values that need to be considered for filter"
        required: true
        type: "integer"
        format: "int32"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "successful operation"
          schema:
            type: "array"
            items:
              $ref: "#/definitions/AreaCode"
        "400":
          description: "Invalid status value"
```

Does anoyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.../areacodes/1`, 1 is a [path parameter](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/), so the parameter must be defined as `in: path` rather than `in: query`. Also, endpoints with path parameters must be defined using path templates – `.../areacodes/{id}`, where `{id}` represents the path parameter named `id`.

With this in mind, your GET operation needs to be defined as follows:

```yaml
paths:
  /areacodes/{id}:  # <------
    get:
      ...
      parameters:
      - name: "id"
        in: path    # <------
        description: "Status values that need to be considered for filter"
        required: true
        type: "integer"
        format: "int32"
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixes the problem!